# Help for solving $ \int \frac{e^{ax^2+bx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $

Tags: integration

Salam,

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solving this integral:

$$ \int \frac{e^{ax^2+bx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
$$

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions. However, the definite integral can, for appropriate limits, and $b=0$, be expressed in terms of special [Bessel *I* functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):

$$\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{e^{-ax^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx~=~2\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-ax^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx~=~\pi~\exp\bigg(\dfrac a2\bigg)~I_0\bigg(\dfrac a2\bigg).$$

More information can be found [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10).

Comment: Many thanks for the time you took to help me

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this integral cannot be found in terms of elementary mathematical functions.